# Why does modulo have to be performed during every iteration?

Tags: python, math, modulo, rosalind

This is one of those questions where I stumbled upon the right answer, but I don't understand why it's the right one and Wikipedia didn't help. For Rosalind, I wrote a simple script for getting the number of all the possible RNA sequences from a protein string (modulo 1,000,000). I know it's not the most efficient possible code 
(partly because I recycle bits from previous things I've made), but here it is:

```
protein = """<large protein string>"""
protein = ''.join(protein.split('\n'))

translate = {'UUU' : 'F','CUU' : 'L','AUU' : 'I','GUU' : 'V','UUC' : 'F','CUC' : 'L','AUC' : 'I','GUC' : 'V','UUA' : 'L','CUA' : 'L','AUA' : 'I','GUA' : 'V','UUG' : 'L','CUG' : 'L','AUG' : 'M','GUG' : 'V','UCU' : 'S','CCU' : 'P','ACU' : 'T','GCU' : 'A','UCC' : 'S','CCC' : 'P','ACC' : 'T','GCC' : 'A','UCA' : 'S','CCA' : 'P','ACA' : 'T','GCA' : 'A','UCG' : 'S','CCG' : 'P','ACG' : 'T','GCG' : 'A','UAU' : 'Y','CAU' : 'H','AAU' : 'N','GAU' : 'D','UAC' : 'Y','CAC' : 'H','AAC' : 'N','GAC' : 'D','UAA' : 'Stop','CAA' : 'Q','AAA' : 'K','GAA' : 'E','UAG' : 'Stop','CAG' : 'Q','AAG' : 'K','GAG' : 'E','UGU' : 'C','CGU' : 'R','AGU' : 'S','GGU' : 'G','UGC' : 'C','CGC' : 'R','AGC' : 'S',
'GGC' : 'G','UGA' : 'Stop','CGA' : 'R','AGA' : 'R','GGA' : 'G','UGG' : 'W','CGG' : 'R','AGG' : 'R','GGG' : 'G',
}
aminos = translate.values()
sample = [l for l in protein] + ['Stop']

score = []
for s in sample:
    c = aminos.count(s)
    score.append(c)

import math
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, score) % 1000000
print result
```

This computes the total number of RNA sequences and takes the modulo of the final result (or so I think). I got the wrong answer twice before I decided to try this:

```
import math
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y % 1000000, score)
print result
```

This apparently produced the correct answer. Why does a modulo have to be performed at every x*y? Am I not understanding modulo or am I not understanding Python?

EDIT: Sorry, typo.

Comment: `score % 1000000` makes no sense. `score` is a list. That shouldn't work.

Comment: Mathematically, these should be equivalent: `(a * b * c) % d`, `(((a * b) % d) * c) % d`

Comment: This makes more sense, but aside from perhaps running a lot faster and not crashing with an `OutOfMemoryError`, I don't see why it'd produce different results from the first version.

Comment: And yet the two versions of code I presented (post-edit) give me different answers.

Comment: Could you reduce the large protein string to a smaller protein string that shows the same problem and paste it here, so we can reproduce it and debug?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you can cut down your memory footprint with `score = (aminos.count(s) for s in sample)`

Comment: also what exact version of python, what 'bitiness' and on what hardware.  It feels like you might be blowing a 32 bit int,  but then this is python....  Would also be potentially useful to grab the output of the reduce in the buggy version and print that before the modulo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, score) % 1000000
```

and

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y % 1000000, score)
```

Is that the first has to work with `long`s up to the product of all the values in `score` whereas the second will work with values no larger than `max(score) * 999999`.

Arbitrarily large integers cannot be stored in finite memory, nor can their product be calculated in constant time, so you're far more likely to hit an `OutOfMemoryError` or take a very long time with the first option

Comment: You know, that's probably it. I checked the result without modulo and the int was crazy big. I suspected it was a programming and not a math question after all.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Still, it shouldn't cause loss of accuracy - python doesn't have integer overflow